# Dynamically convert object using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list of objects of different types, which I need to do different stuff with depending on their type. Specifically, two of the types share a method which I want to use for either of them. What I'm currently trying is this:

```
if (foo is Type01 || foo is Type02) {
    Type tempType = foo.GetType();
    outList.Add((foo as tempType).ToOutType());
    return outList;
}
```

This, however, doesn't work, as the compiler apparently cannot use the Type dynamically. Is there any way of achieving this or will I have to put the two options in different if clauses?

Comment: Try to use activator

Comment: Does the method do the same thing on both types? Can you subclass the types from a common base that has this method (at least as a virtual method)? Or put the method in an interface both classes implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control both `Type01` and `Type02`, interfaces to rescue:

```
interface ISupportToOutType
{
    OutType ToOutType();
}

class Type01 : ISupportToOutType
{        
}

class Type02 : ISupportToOutType
{        
}

var toOutType = foo as ISupportToOutType;
if(toOutType != null)
{
    outList.Add(toOutType.ToOutType());
}
```